# Calculate coordinates for the current resolution

Tags: c#, xna, scale, resolution, monogame

I try to adjust all the textures in the game to the current display resolution. Getting the current display resolution is not a problem, there is already a built-in function that already detects it. Problem, but I have that the game is fixed to Full HD (1920 x 1080) and I would need to convert all components to this current resolution.

For example, the 2D rectangular vector of the game board is (420, 0, 1080, 1080), where the first two digits indicate the position from the upper left year and the last two digits indicate the size (sizeX, sizeY). To convert the first two values, for example, to a resolution of 2K (2560x1440), you should easily use a triple:

X:

1920 ............................................. 420

2560 ............................................. x

---

(1920/2560) = (x / 420) => x = (2560/1920) * 420

x = 560

Similarly for Y:

1440 ........................................... y

1080 ........................................... 0

---

y = (1080/1440) * 0

y = 0

---

What I have a problem with, however, is converting the last two numbers. I need to find a relationship between them and the resolution that can be easily recalculated.

Would anyone please handle this?

The correct result for that game board from this Full HD (420,0,1080,1080) should come out on 2K (560,0,1440,1440)

I tried it over the ratio k_x = x_original / size_x_original

k_x = 1920/1080 => 1.77

and then using a triple:

1920 ...................... 1.77

2560 ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, k_x_2K

---

k_x_2K = 2.36

Size_x_2K = 2560 / 2,36 => 1084,74 which as you can see does not work: (((should come out 1440))

Perhaps if I calculate correctly, for these resolutions the board should have the following values:

HD (1280x720) => (320,0,720,720)

Full HD (1920, 1080) => (420,0,1080,1080)

2K (2560x1440) => (560,0,1440,1440)

Comment: `k_x = x_original / size_x_original` => `k_x = 1920/1080 => 1.77` . But `size_x_original` is not 1080. 1080 is size_y probably.  I think there is a misconception between the ratio between x/y and the with value of the different width of the two sizes.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking about is aspect ratio: x:y or x/y.

Screens come in all shapes and sizes.

The traditional non-widescreen monitor was 5:4(1.25).

The standard widescreen aspect ratio is 16:9(1.777...) for HD tv's. The are minor monitors variations like 16:10 and others, no noticeable stretching among the variations. This will include UHD, 2K, and 4K TVs.

Some displays are classified as ultra-wide increasing the horizontal resolution without an increase in vertical resolution. Your 2.3 falls into this range as do modern movies.

For my games, I develop 3 layouts utilizing the extra space for UI elements and the like.

Don't forget about landscape and portrait modes. Don't assume the monitor is wider than taller.